# open file directly

Tags: c#, text-editor, open-with

I created a text editor in C# and I use a special file extension for the XML file that my program uses. When I use "Open With..." from the Windows context menu, my program doesn't read the file and I get an error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide some code an the error description

Comment: This question is too specific. Could you be somewhat vaguer?

Comment: it doesn't need code i want to know the functions,objects or methods i can use to open file directly from open,with out opening the program first and use open button to open file

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Main()` method, you need to capture the file name:

```
static void Main(string args[])
{
   string fileName;
   if (args.Length > 0)
      fileName = args[0];

   ...
}
```

Then you'll need to pass `fileName` to the code that opens the file. How you do that is up to you.

If your `Main()` method has no parameters, just add the `string args[]` parameter and the runtime will take care of populating the array with the commandline parameters.

If you are already doing that, then this is probably a SuperUser question.

Comment: but the Main like that
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
it doesn't have any parameters

Comment: Add the `string args[]` parameter and the OS will provide the array of command line parameters.  Both are valid signatures for `Main`.

Comment: @khtaby: just add the args[] parameter yourself (see edited question).

Answer (score 1):

but the Main like that

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

it doesn't have any parameters

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple code to answer me

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\wifi.txt");
    }
```

the text viewed in the richtextbox1